# jquery resize window to fit contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple popup window that shows `300x300px` picture, I set up the size of the window to be `350x350px`, but depending on the browser I either get scroll bars or extra white space. Is there some jQuery function that would resize the browser window just to fit the content without any scroll bars or white space, no matter what browser?

Help me out!!

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this..

```
function windowResize() {
   var contentWidth = document.getElementById("YourImageOrContent").offsetWidth;
   var contentHeight = document.getElementById("YourImageOrContent").offsetHeight;
   window.resizeTo(contentWidth,contentHeight);
}
```

You may have to add 20 pixels or so to the values... But I still maintain my original answer :-D

Comment: I tried something like this, but for some reason it still resizes the popup window on each browser differently.

Comment: Yes probably because of CSS, which was my original reply. Try doing the * {} stuff above, this way you should have 0 padding, margin, border, and outline on all elements which should allow you to have similar size window on all browsers. (Not 100% sure)

Comment: document.getElementById("#YourImageOrContent") is incorrect. Remove the hashtag

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem I've faced with this same issue is that "resizeTo" resizes based on the **outside** bounds of the window. That really doesn't help when dealing with different browsers, because the address bar size will be different between browsers, and some browsers will honour the "location=no" instruction, and some will not.

The solution that worked for me (which does include some jQuery, sorry, but which you could probably reverse out to implement it however you like) is this:

```
window.resizeTo(422, $('#my-id').height() + (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight));
```

I've tested this on Safari, Firefox and Chrome and it seemed to work for all of those (don't have a Windows installation, so can't comment for IE).

Answer (score 0):

Its probably CSS margin / padding affecting the document.

do:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

That is a really dirty CSS reset there is tons on the web about CSS resets if you would like a more elegant solution :-)

But this will hopefully give you an insight into the problem..

Comment: This is not CSS related, I need a function to resize the browser window to fit the contents.

Comment: You will probably find that the reason you sometimes have scrollbars or white space in different browsers is due to css and quirk modes.

Comment: The main reason is different browser bezel size. For example Firefox has a fat window bezel where as Opera has practically none. And if the size of the image is 300x300, window.resizeTo(args) will make the whole window 300x300, including bezel, buttons and all.

Comment: If you tried the CSS route and still have the problem. You will have to browser sniff and add a few pixels here and there for the different browsers :-(

Answer (score 0):

if you are poping out a browser window (that is what i understood) then on your opening function, you should do something like this:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
<!--
window.open ('image.jpg', 'newwindow', 'height=350,width=350, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');
-->
</SCRIPT>
```

notice the `scrollbars=no`